# switch js синтаксис проверка несколько значение

Tags: javascript

```
var mass = 1;
var degree = 15;
```

как можно проверить 2 значение сразу

```
 switch (mass,degree) {
      case 1, 15: console.log("hello world"); break;

    default: ;

     break;}
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48129331/6766879

Comment: Вменяемого решения, видимо, нет. Но вопрос интересный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var mass = 1
var degree = 15

switch (true) {
  case 1 === mass && 15 === degree:
    console.log('found: ' + mass, degree);
    break
  case 2 === mass && 35 === degree:
    console.log('found: ' + mass, degree);
    break

  default:
    console.log('Not found: ' + mass, degree);
}
```

```js
var mass = 1
var degree = 15
var searchString = `${mass} ${degree}`

switch (searchString) {
  case "1 15":
    console.log('found: ' + searchString);
    break
  case "2 35":
    console.log('found: ' + searchString);
    break

  default:
    console.log('Not found: ' + searchString);
}
```

```js
var mass = 2
var degree = 35
var searchString = [mass, degree].join(' ')

switch (searchString) {
  case "1 15":
    console.log('found: ' + searchString);
    break
  case "2 35":
    console.log('found: ' + searchString);
    break

  default:
    console.log('Not found: ' + searchString);
}
```